# Reading a CSV file with some empty values into an VBA array

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Since we use Excel for a lot of the software documentation I figured it would be nice to have version control, especially considering it has happened multiple times that old version were beeing used. 
What I wanted to do is to have a skeleton Excel file with all the sheets, indexes and formatting and the data in separat csv files. Additionally in a config.csv I want to define following:

datafile ¦ targetbook ¦ targetsheet ¦ firstrow ¦ firstcolumn

I'm working with VBA for the first time so I'm basically just copy pasting code together but this is what I got so far:

```
folderpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
configpath = (folderpath & "\config.csv")

' Load the file.
fnum = FreeFile
Open configpath For Input As fnum
whole_file = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
Close fnum

' Break the file into lines.
lines = Split(whole_file, vbCrLf)

' Dimension the array.
num_rows = UBound(lines)
one_line = Split(lines(0), ",")
num_cols = UBound(one_line)
ReDim the_array(num_rows, num_cols)

' Copy the data into the array.
For R = 0 To num_rows
    If Len(lines(R)) > 0 Then
        one_line = Split(lines(R), ",")
        For C = 0 To num_cols
            the_array(R, C) = one_line(C)
        Next C
    End If
Next R

' Process first line of config file

For R = 1 To num_rows

    datafilepath = (folderpath & "\" & the_array(R, 0) & ".csv")

    ' Load the file.
    fnum = FreeFile
    Open datafilepath For Input As fnum
    whole_file = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
    Close fnum

    ' Break the file into lines.
    lines = Split(whole_file, vbCrLf)

    ' Dimension the array.
    num_rows2 = UBound(lines)
    one_line = Split(lines(0), ",")
    num_cols2 = UBound(one_line)
    ReDim the_array2(num_rows2, num_cols2)

    ' Copy the data into the array.
    For R2 = 0 To num_rows2
        If Len(lines(R2)) > 0 Then
            one_line = Split(lines(R2), ",")
            For C2 = 0 To num_cols2
                the_array(R2, C2) = one_line(C2)
            Next C2
        End If
    Next R2
Next R
```

I'm getting following error "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range", I think this is because the csv data files contains empty values. So if I have, for example, a completely empty line like ",,,,,,,,,,,,,," num_cols2 = UBound(one_line) sets num_cols2 to a value of "0" because the Split function did not split anything. 
How can I handle empty values? Additionally I would be glad for any recommendations on how I could solve this task in a better way.

Comment: `one_line = Split(lines(0), ",")` splits the line `",,,,,,,,,,,,,,"` into 15 empty strings , your array `one_line` should have an `Ubound` of 14. Are you sure that the textline where the error occurs contains these commas?

Comment: I checked again but it's indeed just a line of commas. If I add "Debug.Print num_cols2" after "num_cols2 = UBound(one_line)" I get an output of 0

Comment: That's very strange. I have used the split-command very often and did just a test, I get 15 elements.

Answer (score 0):

could you open the file and "text to column" the csv? if you can, then you can work easily as a simple table.